# Different default terminals by language in VS Code

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am using Visual Studio Code in Windows 10 to code both in Fortran and Python.  When compiling in Fortran, I use Ubuntu's WSL Bash terminal through the Windows subsystem for Linux. When running Python scripts, I use either the Powershell or the Windows command prompt.

I know that in VS Code I can have a default integrated terminal in **Terminal: Select Default Shell**.

Within VS Code, I have used WSL Batch for Fortran, and the Powershell for Python. My problem is that I have to manually select the terminal I want depending on the language I am working.

Is there any way of setting different default shells for different languages? So that, when compiling Fortran I could automatically get WSL Bash, and when using Python I could get the Powershell? Maybe setting a rule by file extension?

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder? If not, you could try setting the terminal in the workspace settings per folder.

Comment: They may be in the same folder, but I guess I could separate them. How can I set a terminal per folder?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @frode-f, if you can create separate workspaces then you specify the settings per workspace. Basically just separate the code into individual directories and then open those directories separately in VS Code. I don't know if [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) will get you what you want since that's still a single VS Code window.

Otherwise open two terminal instances in VS Code using different shells and flip between them as necessary.